# Is there any angular material table with grouping by header drag and drop?

Tags: angular, mat-table

I have a `mat-table` with a few columns, and I need to group the rows by some of the fields.
Is there something that supports this, or would this relatively easy to achieve just with angular?

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at this:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-table-row-grouping-expand-sort

I provide grouping by columns